# Invalid object name, and invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am getting the Invalid object name 'CUSTOMER_temp'. Error code. I made these two tables and made the temporary table. Also when I put state from inserted. It gives me the error code Invalid column name 'state'. I am not sure if I need this still or if I am able to get rid of it.

The purpose of this trigger is to automatically copy new records to a new table.

```
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
CustomerID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, --Make Primary Key
CustLastName VARCHAR(20),  
CustFirstName VARCHAR(20),
CustStreet VARCHAR(60),
CustCity VARCHAR(30),
CustState CHAR(2),
CustZip CHAR(5),
CustPhone CHAR(10),
CustEmail CHAR(50),
);


drop table CUSTOMER_temp

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_temp  -- temporary table
(
CustomerID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
CustLastName VARCHAR(20),  
CustFirstName VARCHAR(20),
CustStreet VARCHAR(60),
CustCity VARCHAR(30),
CustState CHAR(2),
CustZip CHAR(5),
CustPhone CHAR(10),
CustEmail CHAR(50),
);




  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CustCopy
 On CUSTOMER
 AFTER INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  insert  CUSTOMER_temp (CustomerID, CustLastName, CustPhone, CustState)
    Select CustomerID, CustLastName, CustPhone, CustState from inserted
    END
```

Comment: Can you show the `Customer_temp` schema? And what does `Car` and `Car_Temp` tables have to do with the `trigger`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA here are the updated tables, sorry I inserted the wrong ones.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Perhaps you need `INSERT INTO` rather than just `INSERT` if you're using an older version.

Comment: You do not have a `state` column in your Customers table. You have a `CustState` column.

Comment: @bjones  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.5058.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      11.0.5058.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.14393

Comment: Also, were both of the tables created in the .dbo schema, in the same DB? You should try including the schema name in the statement: `INSERT INTO dbo.Customer_Temp...`

Comment: @LaughingVergil So I took out state, do I keep from inserted in there still?

Comment: Yes - inserted is the pseudo-table source for your new data in the trigger. And don't just remove state - replace it with CustState so the data is copied across.

Comment: You will most likely need to provide the column names that you are inserting into. I would put them in anyways for easier documentation.

Comment: Also, I don't see an Identity column in the temp table... per your comment `The purpose of this trigger is to automatically copy new records to a new table that includes an Identity column.`

Comment: @LaughingVergil I just updated on my table, now why is there an error on CUSTOMER_temp still?

Comment: Show your updates above, so we can see them too.

Comment: If there is an error, you need to let us know what the error is for us to be able to evaluate what may be wrong.

Comment: There error now is saying that CUSTOMER_temp is an invalid object name

Comment: You drop the `Customer_temp` table immediately after you create it. Move the drop statement above the create statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... You need `INTO` after the `Insert`.

**UPDATE** removed `dbo.`

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CustCopy
    On CUSTOMER
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert INTO CUSTOMER_temp (CustomerID, CustLastName, CustPhone, CustState)
    Select CustomerID, CustLastName, CustPhone, CustState from inserted
    END
```

Comment: I tried that and it is still giving me the error invalid object name 'dbo.CUSTOMER_TEMP'.

Comment: Though `INTO` isn't required for 2012 it's good practice for backward compatibility.

Comment: Is it in the same database? And what schema owns the `Customer_Temp` table?

Comment: @WEI_DBA here is the rest of everything.

Comment: You drop the `Customer_temp` table immediately after you create it. Move the drop statement above the create statement.

Comment: I tried that, and it is still giving me the error. I tried dropping the table and still did not work

Comment: I just took your script and it worked for me. You're welcome!